# Duplication posts results are being printed in rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

@post = Post.where("title LIKE ?","%" + params[:q] + "%").distinct.
is printing duplicate posts. If the number of search result is more than one. I have searched internet for this issue but nothing is working.

Comment: `Post.where("title LIKE ?","%" + params[:q] + "%").distinct(:title)` ?

Comment: Do you have a criteria for which result to use when there are multiple posts found? `find` will always return whatever it finds first, but `where` will return an Active Record Relation with one or more records within.

Comment: @MarsAtomic actually when use find it starts to search for integer ID. consider it as id ->("title LIKE ?","%" + params[:q] + "%").

Comment: @MarsAtomic i have checked from the terminal. where is not picking up duplicates. the loop is printing duplicates. do have have any solution to that?

Comment: <% @post.each do |post| %> this is printing duplicates

Comment: There is no possible way this is providing duplicates because there are no joins that would cause duplication. Each post you are seeing is a distinct and unique post. This does not mean they do not have the same title. You will need to clarify why you believe that there are duplicates and/or what you mean by "duplicate".

Comment: You should be posting more code demonstrating the context of your where clause (the entire line of code), any code where you might be modifying the result set and all code where you're displaying the result set (the code block following your iteration process). There's something happening here that you're not showing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.